# Transparent foreground on windows phone page tips?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a windows phone page with a stackpanel and grid contain elements to design the page. 
I also have an transparent image I want to place over the stackpanel and grid, but it should still show, how can I do this?

Comment: do you mean to show the image which is transparent?

Comment: yes over the windows phone page containing the elements

Comment: if your image is transparent, i can't let it visible. do you want to make a opacityMask? you can add a border with opacity instead of your image. or add the image which is visible with opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want an image over the normal controls, with partly transparent background, I would do this by just adding the image last in a grid together with a border element, which controls the background color and transparency, this would result in a XAML page like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY AWESOME APP" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="a page" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Donec tristique leo eu dapibus volutpat. Pellentesque posuere, mauris nec suscipit mollis, purus ante dignissim dolor, a rhoncus tellus diam eu ligula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus eget enim velit. Sed ut tincidunt nisi, at dictum velit. Donec in dapibus turpis. Ut dictum, leo sed accumsan sodales, purus nulla mollis odio, ac molestie elit ante sed lectus." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <Button Content="A button" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <Border Background="Black" Opacity="0.75" />
            <Image Source="/Assets/my-overlay-image.png" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Notice that by setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` the controls behind the image are still clickable.

And give the following result:

[image]